# What quantity and resting time should be preferred for active dry yeast when it is supposed to be used in place of quick yeast?

Tags: baking, yeast

That's the question.

What quantity and resting time should be preferred for active dry yeast when it is supposed to be used in place of quick yeast?

Please specify in spoons or cups.

Answer (score 1):

All different types of yeast can be interchanged.  What differs is the starting amount required and how quickly they rise, and how they are best activated.

- Quick or rapid rise yeast activates easily when mixed with your dry ingredients and a hot liquid.   Typically the liquid added to the flour mix would be *about* 120-130°F (49-54°C).
- Active dry yeast should be activated in a warm (110°F/43°c) liquid for a few minutes.

The two yeasts can be substituted for each other fairly equally by volume or weight.

With live yeast cultures, you must always observe the *outcome*, or high how the bread rises, not just a prescribed or predicted rise time.  Rapid rise yeast will tend to rise somewhat more quickly than active dry yeast, but you need to monitor the progress.

You will find that the very warm ambient temperature that have previously indicated you have where you are makes the yeasts of any type act more quickly than many recipes designed for US room temperatures (with air conditioning) of about 70°F (21°C) predict in any case—this is going to be the more influential factor.

Comment: So, if the quick yeast calls for 2 hours resting time, what resting time should I consider for active dry yeast then at 32 Celsius?

Comment: Less.  You will have to watch and observe.  The recipe should give you a guideline such as "until doubled in size".  But it is too dependent on specific conditions for me to give you an exact answer.

Comment: why did you say 'less'? Quick yeast works more quickly than active dry yeast, so shouldn't the dough with ADY take more time to rise?

Comment: Temperature is very important.

Comment: assuming that the temperature for both yeasts is 32C.

Comment: I am sorry, I just cannot tell you the answer because I have never proofed at such high temperatures.  I can tell you that of the three factors, type of yeast is by far the least important.   *Initial amount* of yeast is very important for short fermentation; *temperature* is very important for all fermentation, and dominantly important for long fermentation.  Its an exponential growth curve whose exponent increases with temperature, but whose coefficient is related to yeast type.  You must look at the result for being done, not how long to expect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8398/discussion-between-saj14saj-and-anisha-kaul)